# Cake PHP, avoid and detect empty fields and duplicate primary key

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i'm not able to catch, inside Controller class, when a field is empty, or when user try to add a new row with duplicate primary key.
this is my model validation array:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'username empty',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'message' => 'not alphanumeric'
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 50),
            'message' => 'too long'
        ),
        'minLength' => array(
            'rule' =>array('minLength', 1),
            'message' => 'too short'
        )
    ));
```

and this is my add action inside controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Admin->set($this->request->data);
        $this->Admin->create();
            // it validated logic
            if ($this->Admin->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The admin has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $errors = $this->Admin->validationErrors;
                debug($errors);
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The admin could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
}
```

but,

- if i leave empty my field, my custom message is not showed, but is showed default cakephp message for empty field
- if i try to add a duplicate element into my database (so i violate primary key), no error message is showed too, and i'm redirect automaticalli to index() action of controller (the default index action that shows database elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicate primary key, set id as unique key in your database table .

> if i leave empty my field, my custom message is not showed, but is showed default cakephp message for empty field

that's correct way for displaying validation messages.

> if i try to add a duplicate element into my database (so i violate primary key), no error message is showed too, and i'm redirect automaticalli to index() action of controller (the default index action that shows database elements).

If submitted data contain field id and that value exist in database, your post will be updated.

I think this piece of line is unnecessary:

```
$this->Admin->set($this->request->data);
```

UPDATE:

> i would show a message if user insert duplicate record. i don't want show default cake php message, but my custom message declared into rule.

```
public function add(){
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // 
        if(isset($this->request->data['ModelName']['id'])){
           $id = $this->ModelName->findById($this->request->data['ModelName']['id']);
           if($id){
              // my custom message here
           }
        }
        //
        $this->Admin->create();
            // it validated logic
            if ($this->Admin->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The admin has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $errors = $this->Admin->validationErrors;
                debug($errors);
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The admin could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Id is declared as primary key on my database, and i would show a message if user insert duplicate record.
i don't want show default cake php message, but my custom message declared into rule.